# How add Breadcrumb to list from react-teams

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-teams, fluentui-react

Is there anyway to add Breadcrumb to List behind emptySelectionActionGroups need to show name and label for my list?

Can i add a button in right side behind filter text?

Is there any example with react code because Microsoft share figma without code

Comment: Can you make an example with the element you want tom add the breadcrumb? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new

Comment: @PauloFernando i try to use `import { List } from "@fluentui/react-teams";` and need to customize it to add - breadcrumb - menu to change view in right side

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/fluentui-react-teams-issue-template-forked-xitern?file=/src/index.tsx  here an example of list i want to customize and add more controls in toolbar